# Show default text if there are no records or when data source is empty

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datasource, webgrid

On page load, if there is empty data source or there are no records, I need to show the default text in my WebGrid.

```
@if (Model.CustomerList.Count == null || Model.CustomerList.Count == 0)
{
    <span>No records found.</span>
}
```

Comment: @Skynet: it's good that you're trying to improve posts on Stack Overflow, but keep in mind that when editing posts, you should try and fix as many issues within a post that you can see at once, rather than simply adding a tag to a question. In this case, there is code that has obviously not been formatted, as well as capitalisation and grammar issues in the post that should have been fixed. See the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) for more information. Thanks!

Comment: @Quantas 94 Heavy thanks yes I should watch out those too but I was skipped.